# Wordpress footer costumization

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am learning wordpress and i want to edit my footer. I am using generatePress theme.

i go to appearence->edit theme->footer.php and i edit that file and i wrote that footer div.

```
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}
?>

    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #page -->

<?php
do_action( 'generate_before_footer' );
?>

<div <?php generate_do_element_classes( 'footer' ); ?>>
    <?php

    do_action( 'generate_before_footer_content' );

    do_action( 'generate_after_footer_content' );
    ?>
</div>

<footer class="footer">
    <p>anything</p>
</footer>

<?php

do_action( 'generate_after_footer' );

wp_footer();
?>

</body>
</html>
```

i don't know if that is 100% correct but it's works and it wrote in web page footer.But now i want to edit with css. i already went to style.css and i wrote

`.footer{background-color:red;}`

but this didn't work, so i was wondering if anyone here can help me.

Comment: Is it a typo that you left the 'd' off background?

Comment: no, my mistake there.

Comment: Your CSS is correct but where you added your CSS and is there another over-riding CSS is not possible to tell just by looking at that code. We will need a link to your site.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS is correct. However the reason why it is not working might be due to where you added it or if the background is covered by another style or due to caching.
You can try to add it at the end of your style.css file and if that fails try adding this:

```
.footer {
background-color:red !important;
background:red !important;
}
```

You should also disable all caching plugins and check to see if the server has caching enabled. Caching will prevent you from seeing CSS changes.

Please note that the use of `!important` in CSS is not recommended, therefore you can try it with removing it but if it only works with `!important` then you can keep it or troubleshoot why it fails without it.

If that fails, send us a link to your site.